# I cant import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, import

I created a Spring MVC web application with the Spring tools suite and I am trying to create this class but when I do the `import` I get this error:

```
The import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer cannot be resolved
```

This is the class i am trying to create

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {      
}
```

I know that putting `WebApplicationInitializer` to a class could create some problems, but when I try with another name i get the same error.

This is my pom.xml file

```
<!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My spring version is 3.1.1.RELEASE i already have webmvc in my library but in my support."list of classes" that class is not there i ihave like 7 classes in there but not that one.

----EDITED

I updated my spring version to 4.0.6 RELEASE and it worked know the class appears in my classpath org.springframework.web.servlet.support.""

Comment: Do you have that class on your classpath?

Comment: how do i view my classpath in spring tools suite?

Comment: Look at the build path, included libraries.

Comment: no i dont have it i looked in org.springframework.web.servlet.support and i have like 7 classes but the one i want is not there

Comment: Then you need to add it.

Comment: where can i find that class?? can i add a maven dependency to create it?? i need that class because i was following a spring example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class is included in spring since spring ***`version 3.2`***

If you have a `version` lower than this in your **pom.xml** the compiler would not resolve it.

Comment: yeah thanks it was that, i found that was the problem too and posted and answer in Aug 27 of 2014, but  my answer didn't have the quality standards and it was deleted. but thanks anyway friend.

Answer (score 1):

The type `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is part of `spring-webmvc`. You'll need to add that library as a dependency to your project.

Comment: <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I have two spring versions in my local repository, Issue resolved after deleting the older version. Then update project.